# HQL query not returning null foreign key values

Tags: java, hql

I have two tables TCI and TLocation. TCI has a column called location which is foriegn key to TLocation table.So my query is like this:

```
select t1.id ,t1.createdOn,t1.location.name From TCI as t1 where  ( ( (t1.s6  <> ''  OR  ( t1.location.name  <> ''   )  AND t1.location.archive=false ) AND t1.archive = false ) )
```

If some record of TCI has null values in this location column, those records are not returned.

In this query I am trying to fetch s6 column not empty or location is empty, so I expect to get all record s6 not empty. However, I am getting only records which have both s6 and location.

Please correct me in query if I am trying to do something wrong.

I tried left join, but it will be a huge change ,which is difficult in my project. Please help modifying the above query.

Answer (score 0):

Left join is the correct option. You might need to find a way to split the huge change and make it, because the database has optimizations to speed the query up.

Alternatively, you can try something like the following:

```
select t1.id ,t1.createdOn, t1.location.name From TCI as t1 where  
((t1.location.name  <> '' AND t1.location.archive=false) ||
(t1.location.name  == '')) AND t1.s6  <> ''
```

Comment: I want a query to do OR operation that is s6 not empty or location not empty without left join. but the location is null. or how can I make 100 tables with all columns' value as empty..so that I can fetch the data